# como hacer un código en mvc

Tags: php, mvc

necesito transpasar una web diario con un formulario incluido,  a un modelo mvc, es para mi tarea en informática soy novato y no se como hacerlo he visto varios ejemplos pero ni uno me ha servido o explicado para entender mejor espero alguien me pueda ayudar... aca el código

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es"> 
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <center> <script type="text/javascript"> var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"); var f=new Date(); document.write(f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());</script>
    
    
     <script type="text/javascript"> function startTime(){ today=new Date(); h=today.getHours(); m=today.getMinutes(); s=today.getSeconds(); m=checkTime(m); s=checkTime(s); document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s; t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);} function checkTime(i) {if (i<10) {i="0" + i;}return i;} window.onload=function(){startTime();} </script> <div id="reloj"></div> </center>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>faro el diario </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bulma-0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
      
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.elfaro.net">
            <b>elfaro</b>
        </a>
       <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.economicos.cl/">
          <b>avisos de arriendo</b>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.chiletrabajos.cl/">
          <b>avisos de trabajo</b>
        </a>
     <a class="navbar-item" href="https://www.comprayvende.cl/">
          <b>compra y venta de articulos minoritarios</b>
        </a>
    
        <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    
      <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-item">
            Inicio
          </a>
        </div>
    
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <section class="hero is-medium is-primary is-bold">
      <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
         <center>
          <h1 class= "title">
        Bienvenidos a El Faro
        <img src="https://viajes.nationalgeographic.com.es/medio/2019/05/02/faro-les-eclaireurs_ebf77ae8_1280x853.jpg" alt="portadafaro"></center>
          <h2 class="subtitle">
       introducción al diario va un texto
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-3">
    
    <div class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
         Inicio
        </p>
    
      </header>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
        <img src="https://static4.abc.es/media/internacional/2022/02/27/guerra-intensifica-ucrania-kMa--620x349@abc.jpg">
            </p>
    
    articulo 1
        </p>
     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/axvoXtpFVUM" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </p>
        Rusia:
       va texto 2 articulo
          <div data-video="W0CDyMQ89TQ" 
      data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1" id="youtube-audio"></div>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/labnol/files/master/yt.js"></script>
    </p>
    America Latina:
    texto 3 articulo
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="column is-3">
    <div class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
      Deporte chileno 
        </p>
    
      </header>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://iusport.com/upload/images/06_2019/2952_leydeportechile-bicubic.jpg">
          </p>
         Seleccion de chile:
         texto deportivo 1
     </p>
    Atletismo:
    texto deportivo 2
     </p>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    
            </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
        
            <div class="column is-3">
    <div class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
    Titulo del articulo
    </p>
    
    
      </header>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
          <h1 class="title"><input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Escribe Aqui"></h1>
        </p>
        
           <textarea class="textarea is-large" placeholder="Describe tu Articulo"></textarea>
        </p>
             <div class="control">
        <button class="button is-link">Enviar </button>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-3">
    <div class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
          Comentanos
        </p>
    
      </header>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
        
           <div class="form">
            <form action="guardar.php"method="POST">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Tu Nombre">
      </div>
    </div>
     </p>
    <div class="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
        <input class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="Mensaje">
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="icon is-small is-right">
          <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
       </p>
          <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-danger">Enviar </button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="control">
        <button class="button is-link is-warning">Cancelar</button>
        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <br><br>
    <footer class="footer">
    <div class="content has-text-centered">
        <p>
          <strong>EL FARO</strong> va pie de pagina
    </a>.
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Comienza por [indentar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n) bien el html.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: necesito pasar la parte de form formulario tu nombre y mensaje a un formato mvc y no entiendo como lo paso o transformo, hasta el momento se que debo sacar esa parte y generar una vista y luego en controlador lo debe unir a la pagina general, y no se exactamente a pesar de ver varios ejemplos de como saco el formulario y lo paso a mvc en sus 3 carpetas gracias!